# Use Picasso with Bitmaps

Tags: android, image, bitmap, imageview, picasso

I have the problem where I want to use Picasso for my ListView, as it has great bitmap caching, but currently have to simply use `imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);`.

I have a list of bitmaps **which are not downloaded or stored as files, I simply have the Bitmap objects as they were originally from the user's camera or phone storage but at this point the app has placed image effects on each of the bitmaps so that they are unique from the originals**, for example:

```
ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmapList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Each list item is simply an ImageView that displays one of these bitmaps. When trying to use Picasso for this, I realized I can't simply set an ImageView to a bitmap like the freedom of `ImageView.setImageBitmap()` allows me to do, but instead I need the image URI. From what I've seen, the only way to get the URI's from these bitmaps is to store the images on the device first, then extract the URI's from these stored images. The issue with this is it takes a while in the app to save all of these images, then extracting the correct one for each list item is an issue in its own.

Is there any way to use Picasso for ImageViews with just having a bitmap, without saving the image to the device first, similarly to how `ImageView.setImageBitmap()` works?

Comment: Where did you get the Bitmaps from in the first place?

Comment: I originally got them from the user's camera using Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE), but within the app the user adds a lot of image effects that I apply to the bitmap so by this point it is a bitmap that is far from the original.

Comment: You have an ArrayList of these bitmaps, right? So I guess it's not clear what you want Picasso to do for you?  It would normally handle caching the bitmaps loaded from files or downloaded from url's, but I think you already have these bitmaps in-memory.

Comment: I have previously used Picasso and loved it, but am just realizing that it isn't necessary if I have these bitmaps in memory. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have the problem where I want to use Picasso for my ListView, as it
>   has great bitmap caching, but currently have to simply use
>   imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

Image caching is good only if you want to load the images from some where except of the RAM which cause take some time, for example if you want to download from internet or reading from file, because accessing those resources is not as fast as the RAM.

```
ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmapList = new ArrayList<>();
```

the above code means all of the bitmaps are in the RAM so you do not need any caching mechanism. if you do not have any URI it means you are using RAM. so best solution is not using picasso and use `ImageView.setImageBitmap()`

Answer (score 0):

Picasso has in interface called Target which you can implement.  It has 3 methods to implement

https://square.github.io/picasso/javadoc/com/squareup/picasso/Target.html

```
void    onBitmapFailed(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable errorDrawable)
void    onBitmapLoaded(android.graphics.Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from)
void    onPrepareLoad(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable placeHolderDrawable)
```

onBitMapLoaded will be called when the bitmap has been loaded from a url.

So for example if you implement Target in you current class you can do something like this:

```
Picasso.with(context).load(some_url).into(this);
```

then when the bit map has been loaded your implementation of the onBitMapLoaded method will be called.  I believe all of Picasso's caching is still in effect, in fact you can even print out where the bitmap came from , memory, disk, file, or network

```
onBitMapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, LoadedFrom loadedFrom) {
  // do something like maybe
  myImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
```

Comment: This is for loading from a URL or with a URI, I am trying to load the Bitmap itself into the ImageView without a URL or URI.

Comment: My first read of your question gave the impression you were downloading the images, but I guess you get them from the users camera?  Maybe you just want to make use of the LruCache class? http://square.github.io/picasso/javadoc/com/squareup/picasso/LruCache.html